# get field value of all documents under the collection

Tags: flutter, list, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called `users` and the documents there are generated based on their uid (useruid in authentication). I want to collect all fields under the `users` with the field of `userReferralCode`. So the structure is something like this.

```
users (collection)
  -userUid_001 (document)
      -userReferralCode (field)
```

So I want every document under the `users` to get the `userReferralCode` and here is my sample code.

```
List<dynamic> usersReferralCode = [];

Future<List> getUsersReferralCodes() async {
    final value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .where("userReferralCode", isNull: false)
        .get();
    if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        usersReferralCode.add(value);
      });
    }
    return usersReferralCode;
  }
```

or how do I just return all the values if the value is not empty in the `getUsersReferralCodes` function ?
so I can just setState it in initState. Something like this one?

```
getUsedReferralCodesList().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        usersReferralCode = value;
      });
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `value` variable is a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html), so you can loop over its `docs` property and then `get` the relevant field of each doc:

```
if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
  var codes = [];
  for (var docSnapshot in value.docs) {
    var userReferralCode = docSnapshot.get("userReferralCode");
    codes.add(userReferralCode)
  }
  setState(() {
    ...
  });
}
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_6).